# Small problem on Android Studio of: Cannot resolve android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am having problems of: Cannot resolve android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

I added the dependency on androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout

You can check that all files have been added to ensure this issue is resolved.
The problem is, the problem remains.

[image]

[image]

[image]

First gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Second gradle.build:

````
```dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    //firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
    // To use constraintlayout in compose
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete line no.25 from your build.gradle(module: ...) and add this line:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But this line of code: "implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'", I already wrote on the first line. Please, could you check? This problem continues.

Comment: yes , then dont add that line again, and see if it works , and if it dont then  try deleting  classpath "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2" from first build.gradle

Comment: duplicated import aside, he should remove all `com.android.support` imports and migrate to `androidx` artifacts instead.

Comment: right! Pawel migrating to androidx will be helpful.